# Timer may not have been Initialised?

Tags: java, android

```
public void reverseTimer(int Seconds,final TextView tv,final Button button,final TextView txt2){

    final CountDownTimer CountDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(Seconds* 1000+1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tv.setText("Time : " + String.valueOf(minutes)
                    + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            if(score > highscore)
                sethighscore(txt2);
            tv.setText("Completed");
            Reset(tv,button,txt2);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I have a reset button that set's the 'clicked' to true and a Reset function that is called when the reset button is pressed or when the timer finishes, I tried adding the following condition to the 'OnTick':

```
if(clicked == true)
{
    CountDownTimer1.cancel();
}
```

But I get the error that it may not have been initialised I know what it means I just don't understand where to initialise it and how? or is there a different way I can stop it outside of this function?

Comment: I think you're going to need to give more context. Where is the reset code relative to the timer code?

Comment: Post some logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an abstract subclass of CountDownTimer. All the code in `onTick` and `onFinish` belong to that that object.
Inside those methods, you can reference the object with `this`. So you can simply do:

```
this.cancel();
```

Or even just:

```
cancel();
```